# Hibernate query not finding "pending" entites in same transaction

Tags: java, hibernate

I've got an app for importing data into a ManyToMany structure.

```
    @Table(name="content")
    class Content {
      @Column(.., unqiue=true)
      String str;
    }

    @Table(name="group")
    class Group {
      @JoinTable("group_content"..)
      List<Content> contentList;
    }
```

The `Content` has a unique column `str` (as seen above) which is used by the app to identify the content already exist in database - and if so re-use that entity rather than adding it again.

This is done with a `findByStr(String str)` method in a `ContentDao` implementation. It's implemented as a `NamedQuery` (`from Content c where c.str = :str`).

When I run an import where both groups and content is new and the some groups refeer to the same (new) content it does seem that my `findByStr` query returns `NULL`.

The query works fine outside of this scenario but it seems when Content objects has been created, but not committed, the query does not detect them.

Currently to work around this I'm actually keeping a `Map<String, Content>` to double check against if the query returns `NULL`.

Comment: Why are you implementing key behaviour manually? And please have a look into the documentation for the correct terms: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-overview

Comment: I'm not sure what part you mean could be done automatically?

Comment: Can you share the code used to add Content? Without the code it's hard to say what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate do not execute all insert statements immidiately. Make sure that before each call to `findByStr` all SQL inserts for all new objects are sent to DB. You can ensure it by doing:

- Tell to Hibernate to take into account all new objects. For example you can do it by executing `session.save(group)` for each new group object (which will take into account related content objects)
- execute one time `session.flush()`

Normally after these all changes must be available for your query in the same transaction.

Comment: OK. Then I wonder what happens if a `Group` would relate to the same `Content` twice (and these would be added in the same run)? The ManyToMany is actually a `List` using `OrderColumn` and thus it's perfectly legal - sorry for not mentioning that in the orignal question.

Comment: You can replace `session.save(group)` by your existing code. I mean there is a place where you tell to Hibernate to take into account these new objects. Reuse this existed code and then call flush.

Comment: Yupp, I think I understand you. But this still causes a problem the group actually contains two new `Content` objects with the same `str` field. What I would need to do in that case is to .save() on each `Content` object rather than allow the cascade to happen from `Group.contentList()`. I think this will require some change in code for Hibernate to accept (as it currently saves the content for me).